# Failure of SIP Proxy Authentication

Tags: sip, invite, jain-sip

I'm developing a SIP user agent application that connects to an Asterisk server and tries to do an outgoing call. I'm using the NIST implementation of the JAIN SIP API.

The application first registers itself successfully. Then, when the application transmits an INVITE request to an X-Lite SIP soft phone, Asterisk responds with a 407 (Proxy Authentication Required) response. The response contains a Proxy-Authenticate header. My application sends an INVITE again, but this time with the Proxy-Authorization header, upon which Asterisk responds with 488 (Not acceptable here).

Here follows the SIP conversation ('>>' indicates outgoing messages; '<<' indicates incoming messages):

> `>> REGISTER sip:10.0.84.30:5060 SIP/2.0
>
>   Call-ID: 7f2d15884ab375fc7b5d32fdd28426d5@10.0.85.3
>
>   CSeq: 1 REGISTER
>
>   From: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=0vmZig
>
>   To: <sip:301@asterisk>
>
>   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.85.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bK493cd4b63090dc9a8027931937b737c9353835
>   Max-Forwards: 70
>
>   Contact: <sip:10.0.85.3:5060>
>
>   Expires: 300
>
>   Content-Length: 0`

`<< SIP/2.0 100 Trying

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.85.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bK493cd4b63090dc9a8027931937b737c9353835;received=10.0.85.3

From: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=0vmZig

To: <sip:301@asterisk>

Call-ID: 7f2d15884ab375fc7b5d32fdd28426d5@10.0.85.3

CSeq: 1 REGISTER

User-Agent: Asterisk PBX (switchvox)

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY

Contact: <sip:301@10.0.84.30>

Content-Length: 0`

`<< SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.85.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bK493cd4b63090dc9a8027931937b737c9353835;received=10.0.85.3

From: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=0vmZig

To: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=as4d134cc6

Call-ID: 7f2d15884ab375fc7b5d32fdd28426d5@10.0.85.3

CSeq: 1 REGISTER

User-Agent: Asterisk PBX (switchvox)

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY

Contact: <sip:301@10.0.84.30>

WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="asterisk",nonce="27ca4a51"

Content-Length:0`

> `>> REGISTER sip:10.0.84.30:5060 SIP/2.0
>
>   CSeq: 2 REGISTER
>
>   From: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=0vmZig
>
>   To: <sip:301@asterisk>
>
>   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.85.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bKe339b4ed9edc5d75379673b6dec7fc42353835
>   Max-Forwards: 70
>
>   Contact: <sip:10.0.85.3:5060>
>
>   Expires: 300
>
>   Authorization: Digest username="301",realm="asterisk",nonce="27ca4a51",response="cfdcdff7ddee99d10c3099e88ffb73af",algorithm=MD5,uri="sip:10.0.84.30:5060",nc=00000001
>
>   Call-ID: 7f2d15884ab375fc7b5d32fdd28426d5@10.0.85.3
>
>   Content-Length: 0`

`<< SIP/2.0 100 Trying

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.85.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bKe339b4ed9edc5d75379673b6dec7fc42353835;received=10.0.85.3

From: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=0vmZig

To: <sip:301@asterisk>

Call-ID: 7f2d15884ab375fc7b5d32fdd28426d5@10.0.85.3

CSeq: 2 REGISTER

User-Agent: Asterisk PBX (switchvox)

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY

Contact: <sip:301@10.0.84.30>

Content-Length: 0`

`<< SIP/2.0 200 OK

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.85.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bKe339b4ed9edc5d75379673b6dec7fc42353835;received=10.0.85.3

From: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=0vmZig

To: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=as4d134cc6

Call-ID: 7f2d15884ab375fc7b5d32fdd28426d5@10.0.85.3

CSeq: 2 REGISTER

User-Agent: Asterisk PBX (switchvox)

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY

Expires: 300

Contact: <sip:10.0.85.3:5060>;expires=300

Date: Tue, 03 May 2011 09:37:45 GMT

Content-Length: 0`

> `>> INVITE sip:302@asterisk SIP/2.0
>
>   Call-ID: 003d85b0d0868f6f2a2d8c324d7f1d54@10.0.85.3
>
>   CSeq: 3 INVITE
>
>   From: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=sJSeLA
>
>   To: <sip:302@asterisk>
>
>   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.85.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bK6704cd9554c0c8e5bc94bc42b606147a353835
>   Max-Forwards: 70
>
>   Contact: <sip:10.0.85.3:5060>
>
>   Route: <sip:10.0.84.30:5060;lr>
>
>   Content-Type: application/sdp
>
>   Content-Length: 106`
>
> `v=0
>
>   o=- 3513403599 3513403599 IN IP4 10.0.85.3
>
>   s=-
>
>   c=IN IP4 10.0.85.3
>
>   t=0 0
>
>   m=audio 40000 RTP/AVP 3`

`<< SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.85.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bK6704cd9554c0c8e5bc94bc42b606147a353835;received=10.0.85.3

From: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=sJSeLA

To: <sip:302@asterisk>;tag=as7358e1b8

Call-ID: 003d85b0d0868f6f2a2d8c324d7f1d54@10.0.85.3

CSeq: 3 INVITE

User-Agent: Asterisk PBX (switchvox)

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY

Contact: <sip:302@10.0.84.30>

Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="asterisk",nonce="55deefb6"

Content-Length: 0`

> `>> INVITE sip:302@asterisk SIP/2.0
>
>   CSeq: 4 INVITE
>
>   From: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=sJSeLA
>
>   To: <sip:302@asterisk>
>
>   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.85.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bK6e3501c0973664fcd7a17affddd23572353835
>   Max-Forwards: 70
>
>   Contact: <sip:10.0.85.3:5060>
>
>   Route: <sip:10.0.84.30:5060;lr>
>
>   Content-Type: application/sdp
>
>   Proxy-Authorization: Digest   username="301",realm="asterisk",nonce="55deefb6",response="47e2c7abe625e4a183726e29c035d7e0",algorithm=MD5,uri="sip:302@asterisk",nc=00000001
>
>   Call-ID: 003d85b0d0868f6f2a2d8c324d7f1d54@10.0.85.3
>
>   Content-Length: 106`
>
> `v=0
>
>   o=- 3513403599 3513403599 IN IP4 10.0.85.3
>
>   s=-
>
>   c=IN IP4 10.0.85.3
>
>   t=0 0
>
>   m=audio 40000 RTP/AVP 3`

`<< SIP/2.0 488 Not acceptable here

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.85.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bK6e3501c0973664fcd7a17affddd23572353835;received=10.0.85.3

From: <sip:301@asterisk>;tag=sJSeLA

To: <sip:302@asterisk>;tag=as7358e1b8

Call-ID: 003d85b0d0868f6f2a2d8c324d7f1d54@10.0.85.3

CSeq: 4 INVITE

User-Agent: Asterisk PBX (switchvox)

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY

Contact: <sip:302@10.0.84.30>

Content-Length: 0`

What am I doing wrong here, causing the 488 response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 488 response is almost certainly because of a codec mismatch between your SIP client and your Asterisk server. In your SIP trace your client is requesting the call use the GSM codec and my guess is your Asterisk server is configured to not allow GSM.

Either re-configure your Asterisk server to accept GSM or try changing your SDP to use ULAW or ALAW as it's pretty rare for Asterisk to be configured not to accept those.

In the below sample not the change to the end of the m= line. 0 corresponds to PCMU (ULAW) and 8 corresponds to PCMA (ALAW).

```
v=0
o=- 3513403599 3513403599 IN IP4 10.0.85.3
s=-
c=IN IP4 10.0.85.3
t=0 0
m=audio 40000 RTP/AVP 0 8
```